# Summing items in list not working? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, list, sum

```
MENU = {"1": 3.50, "2": 2.50, "3": 4.00, "4": 3.50, "5": 1.75, "6": 1.50, "7": 2.25, "8": 3.75, "9": 1.25}

order = raw_input("Enter a number! ")
menu = list(order) #puts the order into a list (2, 4, 5, 2)

def add_up():
    for x in menu:
        global items
        items = MENU[x] 
        return items,

total = sum(add_up())
print total
```

When I run this, the total printed out is only one value in the list, instead of the sum. Why is this not working?

Comment: `order` will be a string. So when you create a `list` with that, `menu` will have list of strings. Also, what is `items`

Comment: ...so it won't add it because it percieves it as a string rather than an integer?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately add_up() is returning the last key in the dictionary MENU, which is 1.25.

Keep in mind that MENU and menu are not referring to same thing here. One is a dictionary and the other is the string you get back from raw_input.

Here's what you might want:

```
def add_up():
    total = 0
    for x in menu:
        total += int(MENU[x])
    return total

total = add_up()
print total
```

You may also not want to use both MENU and menu as this can get confusing.

Comment: ...shouldn't add_up return the keys for every value in menu?

Comment: Not quite... When you call add_up() it does the following:
1) Opens a loop for x in menu, this is the list of your input
2) Declares a new global variable items and assigns it the key of MENU located at the value of the first item in the list menu.
3) Returns the variable items
4) At this point, the loop and function are completed since you called 'return'

So if you input '3' into the raw input, it returns out 4.00, the sum of which is 4.00 and nothing else ever happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MENU = {"1": 3.50, "2": 2.50, "3": 4.00, "4": 3.50, "5": 1.75, "6": 1.50, "7": 2.25, "8": 3.75, "9": 1.25}

choices = ['1','2','5','8']   # make sure choices is a list of strings

def add_up():
    for x in choices:
        # global items        # no need for this line
        items = MENU[x]
        yield items           # use yield

total = sum(add_up())
print total
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(sum([ MENU.get(x, 0) for x in order ]))`